# How to pair scrollTo() to a click event effectively in vanilla JavaScript/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, onclick

In mobile and tablet-mode, I have 3 buttons which respond to click events. When a button is tapped, an info section specific to that button opens underneath. Everything works fine if only one info section is open at a time, but the JS starts to not work as intended as soon as more than one button heading is open.

HTML:

```
<div id="roles-roles">
     <button id="X-button">X</button>

     <article id="roles-X">
     <p>...</p>
     </article>

     <button id="Y-button">Y</button>

     <article id="roles-Y">
     <p>...</p>
     </article>

     <button id="Z-button">Z</button>

     <article id="roles-Z">
     <p>...</p>
     </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#roles-damage, #roles-tank {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 0.5vh;
    padding: 10% 5%;
    background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.7);
    border: 1px solid #f79d1e;
}

#roles-healer {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 0.5vh;
    padding: 10% 5%;
    background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.7);
    border: 1px solid #a1a9fe;
}
```

JS/ jQuery:

```
        $(function showRoleInfo() {
        const damageButton = document.querySelector('#damage-button');
        const damageInfo = document.querySelector('#roles-damage');

        const healerButton = document.querySelector('#healer-button');
        const healerInfo = document.querySelector('#roles-healer');

        const tankButton = document.querySelector('#tank-button');
        const tankInfo = document.querySelector('#roles-tank');

        $(damageButton).click(function() {
            $(damageInfo).toggleClass('damage-active');

            if ($(damageInfo).attr('class') === 'damage-active') {
                $(damageInfo).fadeIn(500);

                function scrollToDmgInfo() {
                    let yOffset = -50;
                    let scrollTop = damageInfo.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    let offsetTop = scrollTop - yOffset;

                    window.scrollTo( {
                        top: offsetTop,
                        behavior: 'smooth'
                    });
                }

                scrollToDmgInfo();
            } else {
                $(damageInfo).fadeOut(500);
            }
        });

        $(healerButton).click(function() {
            $(healerInfo).toggleClass('healer-active');

            if ($(healerInfo).attr('class') === 'healer-active') {
                $(healerInfo).fadeIn(500);

                function scrollToHealInfo() {
                    let yOffset = -50;
                    let scrollTop = healerInfo.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    let offsetTop = scrollTop - yOffset;

                    window.scrollTo( {
                        top: offsetTop,
                        behavior: 'smooth'
                    });
                }

                scrollToHealInfo();
            } else {
                $(healerInfo).fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    
        $(tankButton).click(function() {
            $(tankInfo).toggleClass('tank-active');

            if ($(tankInfo).attr('class') === 'tank-active') {
                $(tankInfo).fadeIn(500);

                function scrollToTankInfo() {
                    let yOffset = -50;
                    let scrollTop = tankButton.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    let offsetTop = scrollTop - yOffset;

                    window.scrollTo( {
                        top: offsetTop,
                        behavior: 'smooth'
                    });
                }

                scrollToTankInfo();
            } else {
                $(tankInfo).fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    });
```

As you can see in the JS, I've tried to make it so that when a button is clicked, a smooth scroll animation follows the click event to introduce the content nicely, but if a second (or third) button is clicked, instead of scrolling to the appropriate section, sometimes it scrolls up to the top of another section entirely.

So: the scrolling behaviour is strange when more than one button has been clicked. I want the code working such that regardless of where the user is in the viewport or how many info sections are open, when a button is clicked (the first time, a second click on the heading will close the section), the corresponding info section opens, and the button heading scrolls to the top of the viewport just underneath the navbar. I've tried to play around with `getBoundingClientRect()` and the `top` value inside the `scrollTo()` function, but I haven't been succesful with any experiments so far.